# Export a changed Bundle from Textmate 2

Tags: development, textmate

How do I export a Bundle with changes (delta) from Textmate 2?

I have installed the Bundle manually and it appears in the `~/Library/Application Support/Avian/Pristine Copy/Bundles` directory.

But I've made edits with the bundle editor so there are also "delta" files in `~/Library/Application Support/Avian/Bundles`

Is there a way to merge these or export a combined version besides manually editing as XML?

Comment: Looks like I might have messed up when installing it… It default installs to the Pristine Copy folder when you automatically install a tmBundle (like from double-clicking in finder). It mentions that you need to install bundles you intend to work on in `~/Library/Application Support/Avian/Bundles` -http://blog.macromates.com/2011/locating-bundles/